# Error en la respuesta de REst en java, objeto no se muestra como arreglo en Json

Tags: java, json, rest

Cuando muestra el resultado en Json de varios registro del Rest que he desarrollado si lo muestra como un arreglo (con un corchete que encierra todos los elementos):

```
{"tb_tipo_producto_1":[{"c_t_tipo_producto":"ACCESORIO PARA COCINA","n_i_cant_productos":"6","n_n_tipo_producto":"010000000"},{"c_t_tipo_producto":"AUTO","n_i_cant_productos":"7","n_n_tipo_producto":"001000000"}]}
```

Pero cuando el resultado es una solo elemento no muestra el corchete:

```
{"tb_tipo_producto_1":{"c_t_tipo_producto":"CAJAS","n_i_cant_productos":"2","n_n_tipo_producto":"005011035"}}
```

El metodo que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/findallsp/{id}")
public Response findAllSP(@PathParam(value = "id") String id    ) {
    Tb_tipo_producto_1Model pm = new Tb_tipo_producto_1Model();
    return Response 
            .ok()
            .entity(new GenericEntity<List<Tb_tipo_producto_1>>(pm.findAllSP( id ))  {
            })
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD").build();
}
```

Comment: Debes usar `serializeAsArray` tal como se indica aquí: [When a list has only one element, CXF return the object instead a js array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18918091/1065197)

Comment: Revise e intente lo que me indicas pero me parece que no es el mismo problema que tengo yo. En mi caso es todo el elemento/registro que no lo encierra dentro del corchete

Comment: ¿Qué servidor de aplicaciones estás usando? e.g. Tomcat. ¿Qué motor de JAX-RS estás usando? e.g. Jersey, RESTEasy.

Comment: Tomcat y Jersey

Comment: Si utilizo Tomcat7 y Jersey 1.18